No C# project is currently loaded. Please create a C# project in order to debug - Source: C# Dev Kit
I'm having a problem with my ASP.NET Core MVC web app. Before that, I was still using it normally, until today when I opened the project again to run it, I get this error:

I know there have been similar questions on here, I've researched and followed them but haven't been able to solve them. That's why I decided to post the question here to seek help. My project is currently divided into 8 smaller projects with separate infrastructure structures. Once every time I click run and debug, the code is not executed and I get an error as shown in the screenshot above.

I realize that, when I uninstall and re-install the C# Dev Kit extension, the error is gone away, but I was getting a new error:
Unable to find a project reference for project configuration item
And the interesting thing that happens here is that the debugger automatically generates the .vscode folder :((. Is this possible to remove this? . How can I remove it and run it without errors?

You can try to delete the folder and restart VS to regenerate. And have you tried to reload the project file and check whether the project reference and path are correct in .csproj ?

@YuningDuan Yep, I've checked this carefully many times but this error still haunts me, try adding ProjectReference by dotnet add reference path/to/.csproj file again but it says it has been added already :(. Anyway, do you know the way to fix when I delete the Program.cs file in each smaller project to make The .NET SDK (from .NET Core onwards) automatically determines whether a project is a library or an executable, because I want only one project is executable and others are all library.

What file do you select in the solution explorer when running and debugging? Can you share your solution explorer? And is there a .vscode/launch.json file in the solution folder? If you want to add a .NET class library project to the solution, you can refer to this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-8-0#add-a-console-app-to-the-solution
